# Swift: String starts(with:) vs hasPrefix

Tags: swift, string, foundation

[`String.hasPrefix`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1410309-hasprefix) (or `[NSString hasPrefix]`) was always part of *Foundation*. However, I just noticed that now we also have [`starts(with:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/2894028-starts).

This method comes from `Sequence` but it also works for `String`.

My question is, which one should I prefer? Are there any performance considerations? I'm used to `hasPrefix` from Objective-C days, but `starts(with:)` is more intuitive and works for other sequences.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`String.hasPrefix()` is implemented in [StringLegacy.swift](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/StringLegacy.swift) as

```
extension String {

  public func hasPrefix(_ prefix: String) -> Bool {
    if _fastPath(self._guts.isNFCFastUTF8 && prefix._guts.isNFCFastUTF8) {
      guard prefix._guts.count <= self._guts.count else { return false }
      return prefix._guts.withFastUTF8 { nfcPrefix in
        let prefixEnd = nfcPrefix.count
        return self._guts.withFastUTF8(range: 0..<prefixEnd) { nfcSlicedSelf in
          return _binaryCompare(nfcSlicedSelf, nfcPrefix) == 0
        }
      }
    }

    return starts(with: prefix)
  }

}
```

which means (if I understand it correctly): If both the string and the prefix candidate use a UTF-8 based storage then the UTF-8 bytes are compared directly. Otherwise it falls back to `starts(with:)` and does a `Character` based comparison.

So there is no difference in the result, but `hasPrefix()` is optimized for native Swift strings.

*Note:* This is the from the master (Swift 5) branch, the situation might be different in earlier versions.

Comment: Makes sense, I expected a string-specific implementation to be optimized. But the docs don't say anything about it (the doc for String's `starts(with:)` should recommend using `hasPrefix` instead). And the fact that it's implemented in String**Legacy**.swift raises eyebrows.

Comment: Moreover, it would make even more sense if String would provide an optimized implementation of `starts(with:)`.

Comment: @noamtm: The `String.start(with:)` *documentation* is probably auto-generated from the generic Sequence method (to which String conforms). – I understand your concerns about the file name, but I do not know the intention behind it.